# I want to change activity and reset timer after it finishes. Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

So basically I made one minute countdown in Android Studio using `java`. As soon as timer riches "**0**", I want to change activities and reset timer. so that when I visit this activity again, timer would work. Here's my `java` code:

```
public class BeginAfter extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDuration =
                        String.format(
                                Locale.ENGLISH,
                                "%02d",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l))
                        );

                textView.setText(sDuration);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //Reset and change activity
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

And here's my `xml` code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#d10e00"
        android:textSize="37dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.064" />
```

Comment: You could create an android service which would be doing the CountDownTimer job. This means that it will be independent of your views so you could acess to your timer value whenever you want without losing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the task by adding the following code to your activity:

```
CountdownTimer.onFinish(){
CountdownTimer.cancel()
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
}
```

Please tell if it worked for you or not

Comment: Nope didn't work! :(
thx for trying tough!

Comment: I did some things and it worked! Your answer helped me! Thanks

Comment: Nice, please tell me what changes who made so that I can add it in my answer!

Comment: This is my code: @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BeginAfter.this, Begin.class);{
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }